# Extract variables from Lua into C++

Tags: c++, lua, c++11, configuration-files, ini

I'm working on a numerical C++ code. This C++ code has a config file with physical parameters of my system. I would like to be able to do mathematical computations and some programming in a config file. Lua seems perfect.

suppose my lua file computes variable `vol` and `mass`:

```
method = cube
len = 3
rho = 1.5
vol = len*len*len
mass = vol*rho
```

I'd like to pass `vol` and `mass` to C++ code. I also would like to pass `method`, which is a `std::string`.

I can do something like [this](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2004-04/msg00201.html). However, in this example, they go through elements of a table one-by-one without relying on the variables' names. I'd like C++ to extract values of variables based on their names. also the structure of the lua config code may be more complicated; I might be writing few functions to get those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can make function such as `GetGlobal(name)`, which will basically return the value of given variable. Then call this function from C++ with appriopriate parameter pushed onto the stack, and take the result from the stack.

Additionally, it might be worth protecting your code from variables with wrong type, using `lua_is*` functions.

I can post you the more complete solution of the code, but I didn't want you to spoil you the fun of writing it yourself ;), so let me know shall you need any additional information.

Comment: thanks for pointing the right way. the rest is here: http://www.lua.org/pil/25.html

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the lua_getglobal. Anyway, using your own function certainly has educational value.